# Creating a Scheduler with OptaPlanner for Project Job Scheduling and Task Assignment

Tags: scheduler, optaplanner

I am working on building a scheduler that operates through REST calls. The objective is to handle N projects, each having temporal constraints for start and end dates, and consisting of N tasks with a predefined sequence. The goal is to determine the start and end dates for individual tasks, considering their expected duration, delayed duration, and potential temporal buffer to be applied to the subsequent task. Additionally, once the scheduling is defined, the next step is to assign the optimal resource to each task based on department, required skills, while attempting to balance the overall workload.

To implement this, I'm contemplating whether to create a hybrid solution that combines aspects of Project Job Scheduling (PJ) and Task Assignment Scheduling (TA). Currently, my approach involves creating separate solvers for each problem: one for PJ and then passing the obtained data as ProblemFacts to TA. I have defined a class SchedulerPJ as the @PlanningSolution, a class Project as @ProblemFact, and a class Task as @PlanningEntity. The Task has startDate and resource as @PlanningVariable.

```
@PlanningSolution
public class SchedulerPJ {

    //ATTRIBUTES
    @PlanningId
    private UUID id;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Progetto> progetti;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "taskRange")
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;
    ....
}

@PlanningEntity(difficultyComparatorClass = TaskDifficultyComparator.class)
public class Task {

    //ENUMS
    enum Priorita {
        BASSA, MEDIA, ALTA, CRITICA,
    }

    //ATTRIBUTES
    @JsonIgnore
    private Progetto progetto;
    private String nomeTask;

    private List<OrdineDiEsecuzione> ordineDiEsecuzione;

    private List<Task> listaTaskSuccessive;
    @PlanningId
    private long id;
    private long idTaskPadre;
    private String richiestaCompetenza;

    //Percentuale di completamento della TASK
    private Integer percentualeCompletamento;

    //Priorità della TASK
    private Priorita priorita;
    private boolean bloccato = false;
    private Integer ritardo;
    private Integer buffer;

    //private Integer durataOre;
    private Integer durataGiorni;

    //Planning Variables: cambia durante la pianificazione, tra gli scores calcolati
    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "tasks")
    private Risorsa risorsa;

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @ShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = DataInizioUpdateVariableListener.class,
        sourceEntityClass = Risorsa.class, sourceVariableName = "tasks")
    private LocalDate dataInizio;

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate dataFine;
}
```

Am I on the right track with this approach? Should the Resource class also be a @PlanningEntity? Do you have any implementation tips or suggestions for handling the hybrid scheduling problem?

Technologies used: OptaPlanner 9.44.0 Final, Quarkus

Thanks in advance for your guidance!

UPDATE 1:

```
public class Task {



//ATTRIBUTES
@PlanningId
private long id;
@JsonIgnore
private Progetto progetto;
private long idProgetto;
@JsonProperty("richiestaCompetenza")
private String competenzaRichiesta;
private Integer percentualeCompletamento;
private Priorita priorita;
private String tipoDipendenza;
@PlanningPin
private boolean bloccato;
@JsonProperty("durataRitardo")
private Integer durataRitardo;
@JsonProperty("durataBuffer")
private Integer durataBuffer;
private Integer durataGiorni;

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"risorsaRange"})
private Risorsa risorsa;

@JsonIgnore
private Task taskPrecedente;
@JsonProperty("idTaskPrecedente")
private Long idTaskPrecedente;

@JsonIgnore
private Task taskSuccessiva;
@JsonProperty("idTaskSuccessiva")
private Long idTaskSuccessiva;

@ShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = PredecessorDoneDateUpdatingVariableListener.class,
        sourceVariableName = "risorsa")
public LocalDate dataInizioBuffer;

@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
@PiggybackShadowVariable(shadowVariableName = "dataInizioBuffer")
private LocalDate dataFine;

@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
@PiggybackShadowVariable(shadowVariableName = "dataInizioBuffer")
private LocalDate dataInizio;

private LocalDate dataDiFineIdeale;
```

Risorsa(Resource) class

```
public class Risorsa {

//ATTRIBUTES
@PlanningId
private long id;
@JsonProperty("nome")
private String nome;
@JsonProperty("competenze")
private List<String> listaCompetenze;
private List<String> reparto;
private String turnoDiLavoro;
private List<LocalDate> giorniDiFerie;
private List<Permessi> oreDiPermesso;
private boolean occupato;
private TurnoDiLavoro turnoDiLavoroSettimanale;
private boolean isRinnovabile;
private boolean isLocale;
private List<CalendarioLavorativo> calendarioLavorativo;
private List<CaricoDiLavoro> caricoDiLavoro; //new

@JsonIgnore
@InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "risorsa")
private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

Listener(new)

```
public class PredecessorDoneDateUpdatingVariableListener implements VariableListener<SchedulerPJ, Task> {


@Override
public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<SchedulerPJ> scoreDirector, Task task) {

}

@Override
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector<SchedulerPJ> scoreDirector, Task task) {
    updateDataInizio(scoreDirector, task);
}

@Override
public void beforeEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<SchedulerPJ> scoreDirector, Task task) {

}

@Override
public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector<SchedulerPJ> scoreDirector, Task task) {
    updateDataInizio(scoreDirector, task);
}

@Override
public void beforeEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<SchedulerPJ> scoreDirector, Task task) {

}

@Override
public void afterEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector<SchedulerPJ> scoreDirector, Task task) {
    updateDataInizio(scoreDirector, task);
}

private void updateDataInizio(ScoreDirector<SchedulerPJ> scoreDirector, Task task) {
    Task taskPrecedente = task.getTaskPrecedente();
    Task taskSuccessiva = task.getTaskSuccessiva();
    LocalDate dataInizioBuffer;
    LocalDate dataInizio;

    if (taskPrecedente == null) {
        dataInizioBuffer = task.getDataInizioBuffer();
        dataInizio = task.getProgetto().getDataInizio();
    } else {
        dataInizioBuffer = taskPrecedente.getDataFine();
        dataInizio = taskPrecedente.getDurataBuffer() > 0 ? dataInizioBuffer.plusDays(taskPrecedente.getDurataBuffer()) : dataInizioBuffer;
    }

    for (Task shadowTaskCorrente = task;
         shadowTaskCorrente != null && (!Objects.equals(shadowTaskCorrente.getDataInizioBuffer(), dataInizioBuffer)
                 || !Objects.equals(shadowTaskCorrente.getDataInizio(), dataInizio));) {
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowTaskCorrente, "dataInizioBuffer");
        shadowTaskCorrente.setDataInizioBuffer(dataInizioBuffer);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowTaskCorrente, "dataInizioBuffer");
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowTaskCorrente, "dataInizio");

        // Se la dataInizio è un fine settimana (sabato o domenica), salta al prossimo lunedì
        assert dataInizio != null;
        if (dataInizio.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) {
            dataInizio = dataInizio.plusDays(2); // Salta il sabato e la domenica
        } else if (dataInizio.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
            dataInizio = dataInizio.plusDays(1); // Salta la domenica
        }
        shadowTaskCorrente.setDataInizio(dataInizio);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowTaskCorrente, "dataInizio");
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowTaskCorrente, "dataFine");

        shadowTaskCorrente.setDataFine(getProssimaDataLavorativa(dataInizio, shadowTaskCorrente.getDurataGiorni()));
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowTaskCorrente, "dataFine");

        LocalDate endDateTime = shadowTaskCorrente.getDataFine();

        taskPrecedente = shadowTaskCorrente; //Imposto la task precedente con la task attuale
        shadowTaskCorrente = shadowTaskCorrente.getTaskSuccessiva() != null ? shadowTaskCorrente.getTaskSuccessiva() : null ; //Imposto la task attuale con la task successiva


        if (shadowTaskCorrente == null || endDateTime == null) {
            dataInizioBuffer = null;
            dataInizio = null;
        } else {
            dataInizioBuffer = endDateTime;
            dataInizio = taskPrecedente.getDurataBuffer() > 0 ? dataInizioBuffer.plusDays(taskPrecedente.getDurataBuffer()) : dataInizioBuffer;

            if (dataInizio.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) {
                dataInizio = dataInizio.plusDays(2); // Salta il sabato e la domenica
            } else if (dataInizio.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
                dataInizio = dataInizio.plusDays(1); // Salta la domenica
            }
            shadowTaskCorrente.setDataInizio(dataInizio);

            Log.info("Task precedente: " + taskPrecedente.getId()
                    + " (Inizio: " + taskPrecedente.getDataInizio()
                    + " | Fine: " + taskPrecedente.getDataFine()
                    + " | Fine ideale: " + taskPrecedente.getDataDiFineIdeale()
                    + " | Durata Prevista: " + taskPrecedente.getDurataGiorni()
                    + " | Durata Reale: " + Period.between(taskPrecedente.getDataInizio(), taskPrecedente.getDataFine()).getDays()
                    + " | Buffer: " + taskPrecedente.getDurataBuffer()
                    + ")"
                    + " Task corrente: " + shadowTaskCorrente.getId()
                    + " (Inizio: " + shadowTaskCorrente.getDataInizio()
                    + " | Fine: " + shadowTaskCorrente.getDataFine()
                    + " | Fine ideale: " + shadowTaskCorrente.getDataDiFineIdeale()
                    + " | Durata Prevista: " + shadowTaskCorrente.getDurataGiorni()
                    + " | Durata Reale: " + Period.between(taskPrecedente.getDataInizio(), taskPrecedente.getDataFine()).getDays()
                    + " | Buffer: " + shadowTaskCorrente.getDurataBuffer()
                    + ")");

            if(taskPrecedente.getRisorsa() != null){
                updateCaricoDiLavoro(scoreDirector, taskPrecedente);
            }
        }
    }

}

private LocalDate getProssimaDataLavorativa(LocalDate data, int giorniDaAggiungere){
    LocalDate dataLavorativa = data;

    for(int i = 0; i < giorniDaAggiungere; i++){
        dataLavorativa = dataLavorativa.plusDays(1);
        // Se la data è un fine settimana (sabato o domenica), salta al prossimo lunedì
        if (dataLavorativa.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) {
            dataLavorativa = dataLavorativa.plusDays(2); // Salta il sabato e la domenica
        } else if (dataLavorativa.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
            dataLavorativa = dataLavorativa.plusDays(1); // Salta la domenica
        }
    }
    return dataLavorativa;
}

private void updateCaricoDiLavoro(ScoreDirector<SchedulerPJ> scoreDirector, Task task) {
    Risorsa risorsa = task.getRisorsa();

    if (risorsa == null) {
        return;
    }

    LocalDate dataInizio = task.getDataInizio();
    LocalDate dataFine = task.getDataFine();
    int durataGiorni = task.getDurataGiorni();

    for (CalendarioLavorativo calendarioLavorativo : risorsa.getCalendarioLavorativo()) {
        LocalDate dataInizioSettimana = calendarioLavorativo.getDataInizioSettimana();
        LocalDate dataFineSettimana = calendarioLavorativo.getDataFineSettimana();

        //Data di Inzio e data di Fine della Task ricadono nella stessa settimana
        if((dataInizio.isAfter(dataInizioSettimana) || dataInizio.isEqual(dataInizioSettimana))
                && (dataFine.isBefore(dataFineSettimana) || dataFine.isEqual(dataFineSettimana))){
            int numeroSettimana = calendarioLavorativo.getNumeroSettimana();
            risorsa.getCaricoDiLavoro().stream().filter(caricoDiLavoro -> caricoDiLavoro.getNumeroSettimana() == numeroSettimana).findFirst().ifPresent(caricoDiLavoro -> {
                scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(task, "risorsa");
                caricoDiLavoro.setCaricoDiLavoroSettimanale(caricoDiLavoro.getCaricoDiLavoroSettimanale() + colcalaCaricoDilavoro(durataGiorni));
                scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(task, "risorsa");
            });
        }


}
```

Comment: Take a look at the new food packaging quickstart: https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/food-packaging - It's a better form than my old Project Job Scheduling example.

Comment: Thank you @GeoffreyDeSmet. I tried to implement a similar version of the example that you provided. In particular, I changed the structure of the Task class and the Resource class (see update). I have implemented a listener (see update). However, I need to add an additional level of complexity to the problem. The Resource class has an attribute of type CaricoDiLavoro (workloads), in whic i need to upodate caricoDiLAvoroSettimanale. When the solver assigns (in what way?) the resource to the task, I would like to update this variable . However, I am struggling to understand how to proceed. Thank

Comment: Sorry, I typically only read+answer *short* questions on SO (with enough clarity and detail to determine the problem)... StackOverflow has a good set of guidelines that help a lot in this regard.